# How to create a user from a id_token with Spring?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I am building a SPA with a spring on the backend. I am working on signing in with Google, most of it is working already: got the id_token with the implicit flow in the frontend and I sent it and verified it on the backend.

I want to have users with roles and manage that locally (so, no adding info in the oidc provider). What are the options to go from the id_token to having an authenticated user in spring? I did not find any example doing that link manually (id_token-spring_sec_user).

I have checked several sources like the Spring Security 5 presentation at SpringOne https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhrOCurxFWU, several SO questions and posts on okta's and auth0's blogs but I am still missing the link.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own (application) specific roles.

Use these steps :

1. Get authenticated from Google
2. Access the profile section from google (username, name etc )
3. Use your own user table to store this info
4. Create admin APIs in your own system and assign your app-specific roles to the user.
5. When you login again you will authenticate against google login/password and roles specific to your application  .

Comment: Fair enough, that's what I ended up doing. Did you see any blog or example of how to do that? It made me doubt when I didn't find any.

Comment: didn't find any tutorial for this. However, it should be easy as the you will only assign a default role to user on first time login.
Later an admin (using admin apis) can change (add new roles) to user.

All you need to do is implement your own authentication provider.

Answer (score 1):

Create an account or session with the **id_token**

Check if the user is already in your user database. If so, establish an authenticated session for the user. If the user isn't yet in your user database, create a new user record with default role from the information in the ID token payload, and establish a session for the user. You can prompt the user for any additional profile information you require when you detect a newly created user in your app.